# How to change dependency in Gradle IntelliJ project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Suppose `IntelliJ` says that my project uses some version of the library, like this:

[image]

If I press `F4` I see the following entry:

[image]

Where did it take it? How to change the version?

Answer (score 2):

You projects contains a file called `build.gradle` which contains dependencies that look something like this:

```
 dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.7'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jul-to-slf4j', version: '1.7.7'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', '1.0.13': logbackVersion
}
```

You can simply change the dependencies there. Afterwards Gradle will fetch the new dependencies automatically, if activated. If not, use the "Refresh all gradle projects" button from the "Gradle" view (shown in the screenshot)

[image: IntelliJ Gradle dependencies]